# Laravel Convert Mysql query to Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I can write simple eloquent queries but have no idea how to convert this query to eloquent. Can anyone give any idea, is it possible to convert this to eloquent or I have to write raw query?

```
"Select categories.id, categories.name, Sum(likes.liked) as liked 
              FROM categories, likes 
              WHERE likes.material_id IN (SELECT category_material.material_id 
                                          FROM category_material 
                                          WHERE category_material.category_id = categories.id) 
              GROUP BY categories.id";
```

Here my Models

```
class Material extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_material');
    }
    public function likes(){
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Like extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'likes';
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function material(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Material::class);
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class Category extends Model
    {
        public function materials(){
            return $this->belongsToMany(Material::class,'category_material');
        }
```

Comment: I think you mistook stackoverflow for [peopleperhour](https://www.peopleperhour.com/)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Was there something specific  that you had trouble with when trying to convert it yourself?

Comment: I think you need to try it yourself first then if you have a error or stuck on something then you can ask it here

Comment: Do you have models set up for these tables and do you have relationships set up between them?

Comment: Yes I Did all other stuff. Models and Relations are all ok

Comment: Ok, cool. Can you explain what you're having issue with the most when trying to convert the query i.e. which parts don't you know how to convert?

Comment: Dont know how to convert the inner query

Comment: Just edit you answer and show what have you tried so far!

Comment: Please can you show the code you have for your `Category` model, specifically the `likes` relationship

Comment: @Rwd i've added Models and relations to question

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you only want to return categories that do have likes or are you wanting to get all categories even if  that don't have any likes?

Comment: @Rwd  categories that do have likes

Comment: In that case please see the first example from my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `likes` relationship in your `Category` model like so:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Like::class, 'category_material', 'category_id', 'material_id', 'id', 'material_id');
}
```

Then to achieve what you're after with `Eloquent` you can use a mixture of [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models), however, we're going to modify the `withCount` call to return a `sum()` instead:

```
$catrgories =  Category::has('likes')->withCount([
    'likes as liked' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(likes.liked)'));
    },
])->get();
```

---

If you're wanting to return categories that don't have any likes you can remove the `has()` method, and introduce the [COALESCE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) function to your `raw` query:

```
$catrgories =  Category::withCount([
    'likes as liked' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(likes.liked), 0)'));
    },
])->get();
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply load the necessary relationships and then use that fact that Eloquent returns [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) to get the value after you've retrieved the results from the database:

```
$categories = Category::with('materials.likes')->get()->map(function ($item) {

    $item->setAttribute('liked', $item->materials->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->likes->map->sum('liked')->sum();
    })->first());

    $item->unsetRelation('materials');

    return $item;
});
```

This would mean that you don't have to add the custom relationship.

Comment: But i dont have Category and Like relation

Comment: this query is giving BadMethodCallException "Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::likes()"

Comment: @merdan Sorry about that, I'd thought I'd seen that relationship. One sec, there are a couple of options that I  just want to test.

Comment: @merdan I have added an example `likes()` relationship to the top of my answer.

Comment: @merdan I have also added an alternative to the bottom of my answer as well.